# How to direct a Comment in a Google Doc to a particular user (who is sharing the Doc)?

Tags: google-drive

Is there an easy way to direct a Comment I make in a Google Doc to a parciular particular person it's shared with?

I.e., I'm sharing MyDoc with 3 people. I have several questions I've entered as Comments. I want to direct those comments to only one person and also have them know that those are directed at them (otherwise  we'll have Diffusion of Responsibility and everyone assumes someone *else* will answer it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah... figured it out:

If you type @ in the Comments you get a dropdown of your contacts. You can select someone from there. Cool! Note that this is not currently available in Google Spreadsheets.

FYI, there are also Discussions available for documents.